# A word describing a person who doesn't overcomplicate things?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to put together a decent résumé and am looking for a meliorative word to describe someone who concentrates on keeping things simple for both himself and other people (boss, clients etc). This one had me stumped.

Comment: You can upvote more than one answer, it's allowed! :)

Comment: perhaps a **pragmatist** would fit that description. alternatively, if you are looking to suggest that the candidate can be expected to hit the ground running with minimal supervision by their peers, something such as _self-driven_ may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Practical** 
[*6. Level-headed, efficient, and unspeculative.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/practical) *He is a very practical person; completely practical in his approach to business*

A **facilitator** (this sounds modern and business-like) [a person or thing that facilitates](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/facilitator) *a person responsible for leading or coordinating the work of a group, as one who leads a group discussion: Each committee will meet with its facilitator.*

> A facilitator is one who usually helps move things along, helps provide guidance and supervision. If you've ever worked on a project, you will know that it takes all members to complete the project, but it usually helps to have someone keep things moving toward the goal.

Comment: Practical was a word i thought of and it does convey what i want to say, i will also add pragmatic. Facilitator also sounds pretty nice. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you might be looking for is pragmatic:
Merriam-Webster:

> prag·mat·ic adjective \prag-ˈma-tik\
>   : dealing with the problems that exist in a specific situation in a reasonable and logical way instead of depending on ideas and theories

Comment: Whilst pragmatic doesn't exactly fit it is definitely a good word for my situation, i will use it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *results-oriented*, *frank*, *direct*, or *candid* fit the bill?

> "Delivered project milestone ahead of schedule; used frank, candid feedback to engage stakeholders"

In a similar vein by way of resume-related words... albeit as a tangent to this specific request, I would also suggest the related notions behind initiative or self-starter. (Of course, assuming those are qualities you embody.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **[low-key](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/low--key?q=low-key)** (also *low-keyed*)

> not elaborate, showy, or intensive; modest or restrained

Also **[level-headed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/level--headed?q=level-headed)**

> calm and sensible

Answer (score 0):

Previously-mentioned *practical* and *pragmatic* should serve, but for additional options consider the following.

• *[down to earth](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/down-to-earth)*, “(idiomatic) Practical; realistic; pragmatic. [eg] *He had a down-to-earth attitude that translated into a straightforward but effective strategy.*”
• *[clear-eyed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clear-eyed#English)*, “Mentally acute and perspicacious”
• *[straight-ahead sort of guy](https://www.google.com/#q=%22straight+ahead+sort+of+guy%22&spell=1)*, a person who sees what to do and does it

Comment: I doubt if any of these expression are suitable for a résumé or CV.